# Azure SQL Server Created Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-cli, azureportal

This could be the first of many questions I raise around Azure as I am currently on a mission to tidy up our Azure platform that has previously been setup by other teams.

Our SQL Servers that have been setup on Azure have had no tags setup and I want to setup some new tags now on all our existing SQL server resources. One of them being 'Created Date'.

So far I have been unable to find a way of getting the create date of the resource.

I'm not fussed on how I get the info, portal, azure-cli or powershell I just need a way if its possible. I have looked in the 'activity log' in the portal, but as these resources were created more than 90 days ago, I'm not sure if this info is still available.

I know this is a relatively simple question but I'm having real issues finding the answer.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way of getting it at server level, but there is a `creationDate` property on the Azure SQL databases.

So if we *assume* that the `master` database on each server accurately reflects the server creation time (as it should be incepted at the same time):

```bsh
$sqlServers = az sql server list | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($sqlServer in $sqlServers) {
    $databases = az sql db list --server $sqlServer.name --resource-group $sqlServer.resourceGroup | ConvertFrom-Json

    foreach ($database in $databases | Where-Object name -eq "master") {
        Write-Host "$($sqlServer.name)\$($database.name) -> $($database.creationDate)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An Azure Sql Database server is an [Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/resource-manager/) (ARM) Resource, so it was deployed using a Deployment into a Resource Group.  And the history of the deployments is retained for the life of the Resource Group.

So look through the Deployments on the SQL Server's Resource Group and you should see the one that deployed the SQL Server.

Comment: @OP - does this still apply if a resource is moved to a new resource group?

Comment: No.  The new RG won't show any deployments for the artifact.